# cant get values printed in to a file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, csv

Iam trying to pass the value stored in the variable fieldCSV to file data.csv...Ive used javascript and php to do this.. I have triggered an ajax request when a value is stored in to the variable fieldCSV, bt this is nt working as the file that gets downloaded prints the php error inside it instead of csv..

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/test/fileDownload.php",
    data: {
        name: fieldCSV},
});





<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, $name);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the file gets downloaded with an error printed inside as "undefined index and file path"

Answer (score 0):

Before you use `$ _POST['name']` do `if (isset($_POST['name'])) { ... }`. You can make sure that the post data is coming through. As a temporary test, change `$_POST` to `$_GET` and access the page directly `http://..../test/fileDownload.php?name={csv-text}` and see if you get the same error in the file.

Comment: after changing to GET, it nw prints the {csv-text},<table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr'>

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are passing an absolute path. Just making sure, are you putting this intentionally?

```
url: "/test/fileDownload.php";
```

Comment: I dint get it.. absolute path in the sense?

Comment: for example, passing it as a relative path will be:
url: "test/fileDownload.php";